# Image inside <tr> not opening

Tags: php, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://api.basvandenbroek.com/deeplink/27341_thumb.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">ID(s):</th>
      <td>148112</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Product ID:</th>
      <td>27341</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Data de insersão:</th>
      <td>2014-01-21 11:16:08 </td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Fornecedor:</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Codigo:</th>
      <td>EN-942</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Numero de serie:</th>
      <td>0010004</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Estado:</th>
      <td>A</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Franchiser product status:</th>
      <td>00273411</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Codigo de barras:</th>
      <td></td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Codigo de barras Alt:</th>
      <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Marca:</th>
      <td></td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Modelo:</th>
      <td>string set electric, nickel roundwound, extra light, 009-011-016-024-032-042</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Descrição L1:</th>
      <td></td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Descrição L2:</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Descrição adicional L1:</th>
      <td></td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Descrição adicional L2:</th>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Quantidade a empacotar:</th>
      <td>N</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Quantidade a empacotar obrigatoria:</th>
      <td>0.0347</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Peso:</th>
      <td>1.25 </td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Comprimento:</th>
      <td>11.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Largura:</th>
      <td></td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Altura:</th>
      <td>92093000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Hs_code:</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Quantidade em Stock:</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">CO_factory_ordered:</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">DO_customer_ordered:</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Novo stock esperado:</th>
      <td>2.75</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Preço bvdb:</th>
      <td>2.41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Preço de exportação:</th>
      <td>1.91</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Preço de compra do Franchiser:</th>
      <td>2.75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Preço de venda do Franchiser:</th>
      <td>12</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Quantidade de empacotamento do Franchiser:</th>
      <td>N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Quantidade de empacotamento do Franchiser obrigatoria:</th>
      <td>N</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Especial Franchiser:</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Data de entrada do Especial Franchiser:</th>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
      <th class="detailsHead">Data de saida do Especial Franchiser:</th>
      <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Categoria:</th>
      <td>704</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Caminho de navegação L1:</th>
      <td>stringed_instruments/accessories/strings/electric_strings/electric_string_sets/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="detailsHead">Caminho de navegação L2:</th>
      <td>stringed_instruments/accessories/strings/electric_strings/electric_string_sets/</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Every thing shows ok, except the image;
it doesn't show on the table, but if I open the image link directly on browser it works.
Can't I have a image inside a `<tr>`?

Comment: Maybe you could invest the time to format your code in a readable way?

Comment: Is the image in question on your own site? If so, you don't need the full URI. If not, then perhaps the owning site has restrictions in place so that you can't steal their bandwidth for your own site. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server hosting the image forbids hotlinking, checks the browser's `referer` header and responds with an error message.

Copy the image to your own server and use your own bandwidth to supply it to your visitors.